# Keep selected treeview row visible

Tags: python, treeview

I have a treeview. I scroll through the treeview rows using the arrow keys. This works fine except when I have more rows than my display will show. The selected row just continues out of view and I can't "see" which row is selected. How do I "scroll" the rows in a treeview so the selected row is always visible?

Comment: Which particular treeview component in which environment are you using? Also, in most treeviews, scrolling using the arrow keys changes the selected item which is always visible. (This is not the case for scrolling using a mouse on the scroll bar.) Is there a difference between the *current* item and the *selected* item in your treeview?

Comment: I am using tkinter in python. This is used on a very small screen so i only have limited items being shown in the treeview.  This is actually being done on a raspberry pi and the arrow keys are from a keypad on the GPIO. I have it selecting the first row on creation, and the moving down the rows when the key is pressed, but if I keep pressing the key the selected item goes out of view, it doesn't autoscroll to keep the selected in view.

Comment: I just found the treeview does have a .see method. I will give that a try.